# Cannot Deploy Laravel Application to Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku

This is my first time of deploying website to Heroku. I got following errors after running `git push heroku master`.

[image]

[image]

How can i solve this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be major reasons that Laravel does not start up, but looking at your error this can be an issue at the **boot()** function in

`app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

file, if you have any DB queries inside the boot method, try to comment them and push again to Heroku. Then create the DB scheme in Heroku and define env variable, after that uncomment the above code and push again.